# Facebook Page Api data?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all the info related to the About page on a public page.

Here is the page im working with. https://www.facebook.com/LADbible/info?tab=page_info

On that page, what call would I make to get the email that's posted there?

This call doesn't work.

```
LADbible?fields=description,about,bio,emails,general_info,website,contact_address,phone
```

it returns this with nothing being specifically about email (even though the email is in the description.

```
{
  "description": "Contact us via email on contact@theladbible.com\n\nWritten by Lads, for Lads.\n\nThe LAD Bible. NO names. NO seriously offensive behaviour to any individual or group/community of people. The LAD Bible should not be taken seriously. \n", 
  "about": "www.theladbible.com | Twitter: @theladbible | \nInstagram: teamladbible | Snapchat: teamladbible |\nMessage us your funniest pictures and videos!", 
  "website": "http://www.theladbible.com", 
  "id": "199098633470668"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using non-existent fields... There is no such field as `emails` for example, have a look at the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page#readfields

You can't access all info present on the facebook website via the Grpah API, that's the baseline.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=LADbible&version=v2.2&

Result

```
{
  "id": "199098633470668", 
  "about": "www.theladbible.com | Twitter: @theladbible | \nInstagram: teamladbible | Snapchat: teamladbible |\nMessage us your funniest pictures and videos!", 
  "can_post": true, 
  "category": "Entertainer", 
  "checkins": 0, 
  "cover": {
    "cover_id": "1235215419858979", 
    "offset_x": 0, 
    "offset_y": 0, 
    "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10392586_1235215419858979_6775646198509937191_n.jpg?oh=49290a96ace64e61b7659bf0be7f28b6&oe=5590FFBC&__gda__=1431644848_286dd200dfd53cca757bf00812acc036", 
    "id": "1235215419858979"
  }, 
  "description": "Contact us via email on contact@theladbible.com\n\nWritten by Lads, for Lads.\n\nThe LAD Bible. NO names. NO seriously offensive behaviour to any individual or group/community of people. The LAD Bible should not be taken seriously. \n", 
  "has_added_app": false, 
  "is_community_page": false, 
  "is_published": true, 
  "likes": 8473213, 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/LADbible", 
  "name": "The LAD Bible", 
  "parking": {
    "lot": 0, 
    "street": 0, 
    "valet": 0
  }, 
  "talking_about_count": 10091113, 
  "username": "LADbible", 
  "website": "http://www.theladbible.com", 
  "were_here_count": 0
}
```

Comment: What would be a good way to access email then? BeautifulSoup?